# How to unit test if there is some json key exists?

Tags: ios, json, swift, unit-testing

I want to test if in my json response some json key exists and for that I write:

```
XCTAssertNotNil(json?["data"], "It seems `data` value has been changed in JSON")
```

So, it passes my test. But there is no such key in my JSON. When I try to debug and type:

```
(lldb) po json!["data"]
```

it gives me the next:

```
warning: Swift error in module MyApp.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

warning: Swift error in module MyAppTests.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

error: in auto-import:
failed to get module 'MyAppTests' from AST context:
error: missing required module 'CommonCrypto'
```

How can I fix that and test correctly?

Comment: Link against `CommonCrypto` for your UnitTest. Also try (casting to `NSDictionary`): `XCTAssertNotNil(json?["data"] as? NSDictionary, "It seems 'data' value has been changed in JSON")`

Comment: @Brandon it passes anyway =/ Also, I'm using SwiftyJSON

Comment: ahh I see. I didn't read the `SwiftJSON` part. Try: `XCTAssertNotNil(json["data"].object, ....)`  if `json["data"]` is an object. Otherwise `.array`, `.string`, `.number`, `.bool` respectively.